GLSL shader compiles on an integrated GPU, but not on a dedicated GPU
I'm working on a program which uses OpenGL 3.3 and GLSL 330. The shaders compile when using the integrated GPU, but not when using the dedicated GPU (Nvidia RTX 2060).
I'm getting the following error messages:
ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED 0(21) : error C7549: OpenGL does not allow C style initializers
ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED 0(13) : error C7549: OpenGL does not allow C style initializers
ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED
0(21) : error C7549: OpenGL does not allow C style initializers (0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link
0(13) : error C7549: OpenGL does not allow C style initializers (0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link
Vertex Shader:
// vertex
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in int data;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;
flat out int FaceId;
out vec3 col;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;


float textureScale = 1.0f / 16.0f;
vec2 texCoordArr[] = {vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),vec2(textureScale, 0.0f),vec2(textureScale, textureScale),vec2(0.0f,textureScale)};

void main()
{
    
    int xPos = (data >> 27) & 31;
    int yPos = (data >> 22) & 31;
    int zPos = (data >> 17) & 31;
    int vertId = (data >> 15) & 3;
    int faceId = (data >> 12) & 7;
    int texId = (data >> 4) & 255;

    vec2 texBase = vec2(texId % 16 * textureScale, texId / 16 * textureScale);

    vec3 aPos = vec3(xPos * 1.0f, yPos * 1.0f, zPos * 1.0f);

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = texBase + texCoordArr[vertId];
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos,1.0f));

    FaceId = faceId;
}   

Fragment shader:
// fragment
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 FragPos;
flat in int FaceId;
in vec3 col;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

uniform vec3 ambientColor;


float faceBrightness[] = {1.0f,0.5f,0.9f,0.6f,0.7f,0.7f};

void main()
{
    vec4 result = (texture(ourTexture, TexCoord));
    result = vec4(result.xyz * ambientColor * faceBrightness[FaceId], result.w);
    result *= faceBrightness[FaceId];
    FragColor = result;
}

I have tried updating the Nvidia driver, but this didn't resolve the problem.

The problem
The problems stem from these lines, from the vertex shader and fragment shader respectively,
vec2 texCoordArr[] = {vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),vec2(textureScale, 0.0f),vec2(textureScale, textureScale),vec2(0.0f,textureScale)};

float faceBrightness[] = {1.0f,0.5f,0.9f,0.6f,0.7f,0.7f};

and are exactly as the errors indicate: "OpenGL does not allow C style initializers". Specifically for this case, GLSL 330 does not allow this. The linking error is (naturally) a consequence of the vertex shader or the fragment shader not compiling.
The solution
The arrays should be initialized using array constructors:
vec2 texCoordArr[] = vec2[](vec2(0.0f, 0.0f), vec2(textureScale, 0.0f), vec2(textureScale, textureScale), vec2(0.0f, textureScale));

float faceBrightness[] = float[](1.0f,0.5f,0.9f,0.6f,0.7f,0.7f); 

Alternatively, you could switch to GLSL >=420 (core or compatibility), which supports initializer lists and lets you use the curly brace syntax from the question.
The general solution to writing portable GLSL code
There are several things you can do to avoid these kinds of problems:

Strictly adhere to the specification.
Use the latest drivers (which you did!).
Verify your shader sources using Glslang, the OpenGL / OpenGL ES Reference Compiler, which - unlike some OpenGL implementations - has the goal of strictly following the specification. The source code of which can be found here.
Try to compile your shaders on different GPUs, as some implementations are more strict than the specification.

For the full details on array initialization, please see the GLSL specifications (GLSL 330, GLSL 420).
EDIT: I've since submitted a more elaborate answer to this question in general here.
Why the shader compiled on the integrated GPU
For some reason, the OpenGL implementation provided by the driver of the integrated GPU deviated from ("did not conform to") the specification. As to why, we can only speculate. Perhaps it inadvertently supports initializer lists for the "incorrect" GLSL version, or it supports C-style initializers in an attempt to accommodate the programmer?
Regardless, these deviations happen in practice, and there is not much the programmers/users can do, other than filing a bug report.
Personally, I consider both deviations that are too strict and those that are too lenient to be undesirable, as both make it more difficult to write portable code.

Two downvotes... Could someone please, please explain where this answer is incorrect, incomplete, not useful, irrelevant, or broken in any other way? I'll be more than happy to do additional research and improve it - or even just delete it if it turns out to be unsalvageable.

I don't understand the downvotes either. I checked the specifications and tried it with glslang before @yun answered the question, and I would have written pretty much the same answer. This is the correct answer.

@racz16 Thanks a lot. I verified it with Glslang as well.
